# table join where

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Table1 t10 (id)

```
id
---
1
2
```

table t11(a1,a2,a3)

```
a1  a2  a3
----------
1   10   a
1   10   b
1   11   b
1   12   c
2   20   d
2   21   e
```

select * from t10 a,t11 b where a.id = b.a1 
how to display

```
id  a1  a2  a3
--------------
1   1   10  a
1   1   10  b //(not display this row)
1   1   11  b //(not display this row)
1   1   12  c //(not display this row) 
2   2   20  d
2   2   21  e //(not display this row)
```

just get t11's random row

```
maybe display this
id  a1  a2 
---------- 
1   1   11  b
1   1   10  a //(not display this row)
1   1   10  b //(not display this row)
1   1   12  c //(not display this row) 
2   2   20 
2   2   21  //(not display this row)
```

Comment: Those are some awful table and column names...

Comment: yeah i am  sorry , it's oracle

Answer (score 3):

```
select a1 as id, a1, min(a2) as a2
from t11
group by a1
```

will give you:

```
id  a1  a2
----------
1   1   10
2   2   20
```

Comment: Yes, but he states, though it is hard to make out, that we wants the first row inserted in the table (e.g. a2=11 for id=1) but obviously he really needs some other factor in determining which row he specifically wants other then the way they were inserted in the table.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer:

```
SELECT *
  FROM t10 a, (
       SELECT *　FROM (
           SELECT b.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a10 ORDER BY a10) as rn
           FROM t11 b
       ) WHERE rn =1) b
 WHERE a.id = b.a10(+)
```

Comment: Please don't post *answers* when you want to add information. You can edit your question (and please do, it's missing some information), or add *comments* to answers you recieved (like this, here). Welcome.

Comment: Don't write an answer unless it is an answer.  Comment on other answers or update your question.  Also, you keep reversing the 10 and 11 in t11 for column b.

Comment: yeah i am sorry, first time ask qustion here

Answer (score 0):

This seems almost like he wants something like FIRST/LAST from ms access.

This can ben done (very closely) in Sql Server using

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        id INT,
        a1 INT,
        a2 INT
)

INSERT INTO @Table (id,a1,a2) SELECT 1, 1, 11
INSERT INTO @Table (id,a1,a2) SELECT 1, 1, 10
INSERT INTO @Table (id,a1,a2) SELECT 1, 1, 12
INSERT INTO @Table (id,a1,a2) SELECT 2, 2, 20
INSERT INTO @Table (id,a1,a2) SELECT 2, 2, 21

SELECT  *
FROM    @Table t
WHERE   a2 = (SELECT TOP 1 a2 FROM @Table WHERE id = t.id AND a1 = t.a1)
```